# Securely counting views on cached static pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, caching

I'm looking for a method for async pageview counting on cached pages.

Because of a high traffic I am generating static html pages which are served directly by web server without even running php or connecting to database.

The problem is that I need to do delayed pageview counting. That means counting the view after a specified time spend on the page.

Only thing I can think of is some ajax call. It would impair the caching a little, because people who spend the time on the page will eventually trigger the full request (with php/db). But I think even that will help a little.

On the other hand I need the pageviews to be secure. And if it all happens in JS, then everyone can spoof a lot of views.

I also thought of Google Analytics, which I am actually using. I can use API to pull pageviews, but they are counted right after the user opens the page and not delayed. There is also possible use of events, but again, these can be spoofed. Also I am displaying these views count to users, so I'd like it to be as accurate and up-to-date as possible (a little delay is tolerated), which I think GA is not.

Can you think of some better solution? I've heard that static cached pages are quite widely used, so there must be some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one-time-only token in the AJAX Call, such that every call can only be made once. Or you can setTimeout the GA of Analytics, but that is not a good idea.

Comment: Sure I can generate a token, but the idea is generating a static page once and then serving it to thousands of visitors. If I generated a single token, it would be reusable and thus could be spoofed. Same goes for GA